# JSF reRender custom component

Tags: jsf, richfaces, custom-component, ajax4jsf, rerender

I have a JSF 1.2 custom component working fine. The files are: Cabecalho.java and CabecalhoComponente.java, the tag and the component.

I want to use rerender to it (edited: using an richfaces a4j:commandButton) but not working. It have an attribute with EL getting the current time in millis, the value doesn't update in output, but when i debug application, I can see new value setting to property on restoreState method.

Why the output is not updated?

Thanks.

Comment: I encounter similar problem with my custom compoment for phone numbers. I had page with rich:dataTable with users and each record had edit a4j:commandButton which opened rich:modalPanel for editing given user. Every fields were rendered properly except my custom phone component which was null.
It turns out that i had design flaw in my component (related to saving and restoring state).

Attach your component source code, maybe I will help.